# How to add clickable link for every state in "U.S. Map" JQuery plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, clickable

I am new on java-script, JQuery . 
I have successfully implemented U.S. Map jQuery plugin via on my Shopify site.
But can't add clickable link for every state . How can i add link for every state ?

[Map_Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5aoFu.gif)

And here is U.S. Map Plugin Documentation :
https://newsignature.github.io/us-map/

Here is my work in codeopen:
https://codepen.io/mesbahworld/pen/gQqaVo/

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#map').usmap({});
  });

var state_data = {
    MD: {fill: '#364650'},
    VA: {fill: 'yellow', fullname:'Varginia', src: 'http://raphaeljs.com/'},
  };

$('#map').usmap({
  stateStyles: {fill: '#A4AA88'},
  stateHoverStyles: {fill: 'teal'},
  stateHoverAnimation: 0,
  showLabels: true,
  stateSpecificStyles: state_data
  //stateSpecificHoverStyles: {MD: {fill: 'red'}}
});

$('#map').on('usmapmouseover', function(event, data) {
  // Output the abbreviation of the state name to the console
  $("#name span").html(data.name);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add

```
$('#map').on('usmapclick', function(event, data) {
    var state=data.name; 
    if(state=="WY") window.location='http://google.com';
    if(state=="KS") window.location='http://yahoo.com';
    // ....
    // ....
});
```

Example

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#map').usmap({
    });
  });
  


var state_data = {
    MD: {fill: '#364650'},
    VA: {fill: 'yellow', fullname:'Varginia', src: 'http://raphaeljs.com/'},
  };

$('#map').usmap({
  stateStyles: {fill: '#A4AA88'},
  stateHoverStyles: {fill: 'teal'},
  stateHoverAnimation: 0,
  showLabels: true,
  stateSpecificStyles: state_data
  //stateSpecificHoverStyles: {MD: {fill: 'red'}}
});

$('#map').on('usmapmouseover', function(event, data) {
  // Output the abbreviation of the state name to the console
  $("#name span").html(data.name);
});

$('#map').on('usmapclick', function(event, data) {
  var state=data.name; 
  if(state=="WY") window.location='http://google.com';
  if(state=="KS") window.location='http://yahoo.com';
  // ....
  // ....
});
```

```css
.section {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.map {
  width: 600px;
  height: 400px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.name {
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: "Lato";
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #000000;
  padding-top: 0px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 40px;

  
  
}

svg path {
  stroke-width: 1px;
  stroke: white;
}
```

```html
<script src='//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script src='https://newsignature.github.io/us-map/js/libs/raphael.js'></script>
<script src='https://newsignature.github.io/us-map/js/libs/jquery.usmap.js'></script>

<div class="row-map">
<div class="section">

<div class="name" id="name">Shop By State: <span> Select From Map </span>
</div>
<div id="clicked-state"></div>
<div class="map" id="map"></div>

</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is it possible if i want to show full name of all state on mouse-hover-over instead of Short name . (ex: "VA" will show "virginia" on mouseover.

Comment: @Md.MesbahUddin  replace "usmapmouseover" - $('#map').on('usmapmouseover', function(event, data) {
  if(state=="VY") fullname='Virginia';
  $("#name span").html(fullname);
});

Comment: @Md.MesbahUddin  - $('#map').on('usmapmouseover', function(event, data) {
  var state=data.name; 
  if(state=="VY") fullname='Virginia';
  $("#name span").html(fullname);
});